# Using a switch case to write button values to variable

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, case

I am trying to get values from my buttons using a switch case.
But everytime when I am using this code it crashes..
Does anyone know how to fix it.

Also, this code is not finished so I am missing 7 buttons but thats for later.

```
public void startGame(View v){

    String randText = "";
    String test = "10";
    String test1 = "11";

    Random randGen = new Random();

    int rando = randGen.nextInt(10);
    randText = Integer.toString(rando);

    TextView RandomValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomValueTv);
    RandomValue.setText(randText);

    randomNumbersRbra();

    TimerGame();

    Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startGameBtn);
    start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    TextView go = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGo);
    go.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Button btnTap1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap1);
    Button btnTap2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap2);
    Button btnTap3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap3);
    Button btnTap4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap4);
    Button btnTap5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap5);
    Button btnTap6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap6);
    Button btnTap7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap7);
    Button btnTap8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap8);
    Button btnTap9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap9);

    TextView tvtest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTv);
    tvtest.setText(test.toString());

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.tap1:
        tvtest.setText(test1.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.tap2:
        tvtest.setText(test1.toString());
    }
    btnTap1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    btnTap2.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}
```

Logcat

```
> 05-22 14:06:22.271: D/dalvikvm(29893): Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-22 14:06:22.821: D/libEGL(29893): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-22 14:06:22.821: D/libEGL(29893): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-22 14:06:22.881: D/libEGL(29893): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-22 14:06:22.941: D/OpenGLRenderer(29893): Enabling debug mode 0
05-22 14:06:24.753: D/dalvikvm(29893): JIT code cache reset in 13 ms (4096 bytes 2/0)
05-22 14:06:24.763: D/dalvikvm(29893): GC_CONCURRENT freed 172K, 7% free 11024K/11783K, paused 3ms+26ms, total 127ms
05-22 14:06:25.283: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29893): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-22 14:06:25.283: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29893): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-22 14:06:26.034: D/AndroidRuntime(29893): Shutting down VM
05-22 14:06:26.044: W/dalvikvm(29893): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416c92a0)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3660)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3655)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    ... 12 more
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.roc.quickynumbers.Game2 cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    at com.roc.quickynumbers.Game2.startGame(Game2.java:121)
05-22 14:06:26.064: E/AndroidRuntime(29893):    ... 15 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `Activity` (or whatever the method is in) does not implement `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Change :btnTap1.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Activity implements OnClickListener

Comment: Then i get this error: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: After implements OnclickListener, is Shows add unimplemented methods. Do that

Comment: it showing unimplemented method cause your class does not contain 'override onClick' method check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First make sure to  implement onclicklistener in your class....**

```
public void startGame(View v){

String randText = "";
String test = "10";
String test1 = "11";

Random randGen = new Random();

int rando = randGen.nextInt(10);
randText = Integer.toString(rando);

TextView RandomValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomValueTv);
RandomValue.setText(randText);

randomNumbersRbra();

TimerGame();

Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startGameBtn);
start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

TextView go = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGo);
go.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Button btnTap1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap1);
Button btnTap2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap2);
Button btnTap3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap3);
Button btnTap4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap4);
Button btnTap5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap5);
Button btnTap6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap6);
Button btnTap7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap7);
Button btnTap8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap8);
Button btnTap9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap9);

TextView tvtest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTv);
tvtest.setText(test.toString());

//OnClickListener like below:
btnTap1.setOnClickListener(this);
btnTap2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

//And override method like below:
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.tap1:
        // do something
        break;
    case R.id.tap2:
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I will do that! haha

Answer (score 0):

Activity implements OnClickListener.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.tap1: 
        tvtest.setText(test1.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.tap2: 
        tvtest.setText(test1.toString());
        break;
    default:
    break;
    }

}
```